# Trying to initialize a 2d zero array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm very new to C++ and was trying to initialize a large 2d zero array. However, if I run this it gives no errors but "test a" is not printed. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "test a" << endl;
    int arrone[60480][12] = {};
}
```

Comment: Your array takes 2.7 MB, you probably have stack overflow.

Comment: Your huge array overflows stack and program crashes. Instead of plain array use heap-based `std::vector<std::array<int, 12>> arrone(60480);`, for this include `#include <vector>` and `#include <array>`. Then you can use it same like plain array, e.g. access `arrone[i][j]`.